# how write the following matlab code if want to fill data by for loop?

Tags: matlab

the given matlab code want to write by using "for loop"

how I can do that ?

```
    g = {'P1','P1','P2','P2','P3','P3','P4','P4'};
```

I want this data by using for loop:

```
  for f_no=1:8
      g{f_no}=p(count);
      count=count+1;
  end
```

consider p has all dataset, how do I fill this as dynamic way into cell 'g'?
which will work as :
g = {'P1','P1','P2','P2','P3','P3','P4','P4'};

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: I want to define a class group by 'g' variable for function of class = knnclassify(a,b,g); where I want store the g cell value at run time after storing domain value of g I want to pass it as argument in function as follow : knnclassify(a,b,g);

Comment: Your example is not clear enough, provide us with the desired input / output behavior.

Answer (score 3):

There are probably dozens of ways to do what you are asking.  Here are 2.

```
%Loop
g = cell(8,1);
for p=1:4
    g{p*2-1} = num2str(p,'P%d');
    g{p*2}   = num2str(p,'P%d');
end

%No Loop
g = cellstr(num2str(sort([1:4 1:4].'),'P%d'));
```

Comment: ok, but I want to store any string in position of p1 to p8, p1 to p8 that was example only instead of p1 to p8 we can store any string within dynamic length of cell ?

Comment: I want to define a class group by 'g' variable for function of class = knnclassify(a,b,g); where I want store the g cell value at run time after storing domain value of g I want to pass it as argument in function as follow : knnclassify(a,b,g);

Answer (score 3):

```
count = 1;
for f_no=1:8
    g{f_no}=['P' num2str(count)];
    count=count+1;
end
```

gives you

```
g = { 'P1' 'P2' 'P3' 'P4' 'P5' 'P6' 'P7' 'P8' }
```

OTOH,

```
count = 1;
for f_no=1:8
    g{f_no}=['P' num2str(floor(count))];
    count=count+.5;
end
```

gives you

```
g = { 'P1' 'P1' 'P2' 'P2' 'P3' 'P3' 'P4' 'P4' }
```

Comment: ok, but I want to store any string in position of p1 to p8, p1 to p8 that was example only instead of p1 to p8 we can store any string within dynamic length of cell ?

Comment: I want to define a class group by 'g' variable for function of class = knnclassify(a,b,g); where I want store the g cell value at run time after storing domain value of g I want to pass it as argument in function as follow : knnclassify(a,b,g);

Comment: @sanjaygupta I don't understand what prevents you from storing anything you want in `p{1}` to `p{8}`.

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
N = [1 2 3 4];
P = repelem(N,2);
result = arrayfun(@(x)sprintf('P%d',x),P,'UniformOutput',false);
```

It makes use of the [repelem function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) for duplicating each number in the vector `N` and of the [arrayfun function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) for converting each number into a properly formatted string.

Alternatively, you can also use the undocumented function `sprintfc` and change the last line as follows:

```
result = sprintfc('P%d',P)
```

Always try to vectorize your code as much as possible when using Matlab, it performs sooooooo much better!

Answer (score 0):

```
for f_no=1:4
    g{2*f_no-1}=['P' num2str(f_no)];
    g{2*f_no}=['P' num2str(f_no)];
end
```

It looks like 'P1' denotes p(1) cell value in which case the answer will be the same

```
n=size(p);

for f_no=1:n
    g{2*f_no-1}=p(f_no);
    g{2*f_no}=p(f_no);
end
```